# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership, dataprovider

I've seen several posts about this, but none of the answers seem to work.

I'm trying to set up simplemembership and I keep getting this error when `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(...)` is called

Here is the ConnectionsStrings entry:

```
<add name="JBarterMain" connectionString="Data Source=winsrv01;Initial Catalog=ProvausioJBarter;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I tried adding the following to my machine config in the .net 4.0 x64 folder:

```
<add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
```

I'm getting absolutely nowhere. This seems incredibly odd to me that this wouldn't work out of the box. I had another project a few months ago (broken currently so I can't verify that it still works) that was working just fine and I didn't have to do any additional configuration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on how to set up simple membership [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185410/simple-membership-provider-in-mvc/21662491#21662491). Also I prefer to ditch the filters and initialize it directly on application start