# How to initialize simple membership in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, asp.net-membership, simplemembership, targetinvocationexception

How to initialize simple membership in ASP.NET MVC4

Hi, I'm working on ASP.NET MVC4.
As you know, membership/authentication mechanism is disabled in ASP.NET MVC4;
if we want to enable it, we need to:

1) edit the follow line(in the constructor of the class SimpleMembershipInitializer, file InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs)

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "users", "id", "username", autoCreateTables: true);
```

2) add a new key to  in your Web.Config section.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
    ...
</appSettings>
```

Right?
You can find some information [here](http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.it/2013/02/aspnet-mvc-4-membership-users-passwords.html) and [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1840044.aspx).

**NB:** I have already created table 'users' in my database, DefaultConnection is set correctly.

**EDIT:** let "DefaultConnectionString" be

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SimpleAuthenticationMvc4-20140209174604;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I attempt to "login" in my web-application, I get a TargetInvocationException when calling EnsureInitialized():
here the complete source code of my InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute class:

```
/* class MyApp.Filters.InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute */

namespace MyApp.Filters
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
        private static object _initializerLock = new object();
        private static bool _isInitialized;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
            // HERE i _always_ get TargetInvocationException
            LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
        }

        private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
        {
            public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

                try
                {
                    using (var context = new UsersContext())
                    {
                        if (!context.Database.Exists())
                        {
                            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                        }
                    }

                    /* DefaultConnection and table 'users' should/seems to be OK */
                    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "users", "id", "username", autoCreateTables: true);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Someone suggested me that this error can mean that the simple membership is initialized in another part of the application, but I do not understand where this might happen: 
Here is the text of my global.asax.cs:

```
/* file global.asax.cs */

namespace MyApp
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing strange, as you can see.
I also tried to move around within the file global.asax.cs, as is suggested here, but even so I get the same exception.

**I have no special requirements: I only want to log-in in my MVC 4 application, as I do with MVC3 app I have written previously.**

Can anyone suggest me where is the mistake?

Thanks!

IT

Answer (score 0):

Okay I am assuming you want to use your existing users table right? Is "DefaultConnection" your connection string? I am assuming not. So you should use your connection string instead.

Initially I also ran into an initialization issue so I preferred to ditch the filter and initialize it directly in global.asax by

```
if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
            {
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("YOUR_DB_CONTEXT", "USER_TABLE", "ID_COLUMN", "USERNAME_COLUMN", true);
            }
```

I posted my tutorial on setting it up [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185410/simple-membership-provider-in-mvc/21662491#21662491). I think it can help you.

Comment: Hi @Lokesh, Thank for Your reply. Yes, My "DefaultConnectionString" is supposed to be right.

Comment: Okay. Did you try ditching the filter and initializing it directly?

Comment: Yes, My "DefaultConnectionString" is supposed to be right. I add some edit to post: is it "like-is-supposed-to-be"(well-formed)?. Now I have three little-question: a) modify System.web by adding providers is mandatory? None of the tutorials I read talked about it! b) What is, in practice, the difference between ASP.NET MVC 4 "Simple Membership" and ordinary "local log in"?

Comment: c) Where - that is, in which method - should be called

WebSecurity.CreateUser("Username","Password");

?

Comment: a) I am not sure about that but I am guessing it should be necessary to specify the membership provider along with the connection string. I also followed many tutorials and found this setting to work correctly.

b) I assume by "local-log-in" you mean .net Membership right? So there are many differences but mainly simple membership let's you use your database table for user which results in better user profiles and a single database.

Comment: c) You should create users in your controllers. And I am sorry I made a mistake, it is CreateAccount() not CreateUser

Comment: Yes, when I say "Local" login I means "standard" ASP.NET MVC Login, what whe use when enableSimpleMembership = false.

Comment: There is no local logins. You have to setup either asp.net membership or create your login system. Which is it ?

Comment: has this been solved ?? Please update as this will be helpfull to alot other viewers.